# Get the browser's highlighted text into a UTF8 encoded javascript string

Tags: javascript, dom, web-applications, unicode

I'm new to javascript and do not have a good grasp of its unicode handling. If I understand correctly it's kind of like C/C++ where a string contains a binary sequence without any encoding info.

When I use something like `var str=window.getSelection().toString()` to get the highlighted text, will the resulting string have the same encoding as the web-page? If so, what's the best way of finding out that encoding and converting it to a unicode one (e.g. UTF8)?

Comment: The encoding used in JavaScript is either UCS-2 or UTF-16.

Comment: [More info about Jack's comment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-2).

Comment: [And more here](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding)

Comment: It largely depends on how you wish to use it; if you're sending the value via AJAX, it would get converted to the page's character set (afaik).

Comment: Thanks! I think I had it wrong and my question doesn't make a lot of sense. My original problem was not related to sending the information in str but rather to using it with regular expressions and string functions. I wrongly assumed the encoding of the str variable above will be the same as the page encoding, but if javascript automatically converts the selected text to UCS-2/UTF-16 before handing it over to me in the str variable then I'm all good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Strings in Javascript are not like "strings" in C or PHP, which are actually byte arrays and have encoding semantics. Strings in Javascript are quite different than that and are like strings in Java/C# or Python's unicode type.

They are strings of abstract characters, at least if you don't try to have non-BMP characters. In practice, you don't have to worry about that, I am just mentioning it for completeness.

As per above, `var str=window.getSelection().toString()` does not have any encoding semantics, it's just a string of the characters that are selected. You don't state any actual problem in your question, but if you are wondering if "special" characters will just work in Javascript, well, they do just work.

Comment: "You don't have to worry about that, I am just mentioning it for completeness." Erm, what?? Of course you have to worry about that.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Why? I am not interested in theoretical explanations btw - pratical only.

Comment: Because I get angry when bananas  break the software I am using.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes it most likely doesn't break even if someone were annoying enough to look up useless non-BMP characters that only show correctly for those very people who know how to look them up.

Comment: Because the truth is that *like* strings in C or PHP or Java or C#, strings in JavaScript "are actually [word] arrays and have encoding semantics". The first two paragraphs in this answer are wrong and completely misleading.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes There is a huge difference between having to know the encoding of a given PHP string and decode it every time some operation is needed vs just working with it.

Comment: And which is that? UCS-2 or UTF-16?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes You don't have to know in practice. See my comment about non-BMP characters.

Comment: Except when you do (regular expressions being the textbook example).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes, the software might then break when a savvy user looks up a `` (shows up as a box for me) and tries to insert it. I am saying it is not practical or cost effective to try to handle these situations because that implies using specialized string/regex functions for everything.

Comment: FTR, a banana was just a random example; better examples are the three blocks of CJK Unified Ideographs in Plane 2. It is only impractical to handle these because JavaScript strings are not strings of abstract characters.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes AFAIK those are not used / very rarely used in moden CJK. If there is a reason that these must be absolutely handled correctly, then you have no choice but worry about them of course. But in practice, most programs don't have to absolutely handle them correctly. I did state in my post that they are strings of abstract characters *if* you don't have to handle non-BMP.

Comment: This comes down to pragmatism vs idealism, I have already edited the post to clarify that I am stating from a pragmatic point of view.

Comment: You are plain wrong. A javascript string is just UCS-2 or UTF-16, it is not any more abstract than C or PHP strings.

Comment: @DeadMG if you know python 2, a PHP string is like the str type and a Javascript string is like the unicode type (when compiled with UTF-16- there is an option to compile with UTF-32). If these are the same, what's the point? A PHP string is actually byte array of arbitrary bytes that do not necessarily even represent characters in any encoding.

Comment: UTF-16 is an encoding just as much as ASCII is an encoding.

Comment: @DeadMG Ok. But a PHP string / Python 2 str / c# byte[] / java byte[] are much harder to work with because every operation needs to know the encoding. Whereas with a more abstract String type like Javascript strings / Java strings / Python 2 unicode type etc you don't.